# Изменение размера изображения при масштабировании в css

Tags: css, css3

Как при изменении размера окна сделать изменение размера картинки?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss3%5D%5Bcss%5D+media

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример, тут в окне стака он не работает, попробуйте выполнить его в вашей среде разработки:

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://stackexchange.com/content/img/hero/check.png" width="100" height="100">
<p>Resize the browser window to see how the image will scale.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Через media queries (медиа-запросы).

Comment: А можно пример? У меня ничего не получается

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 540px){
 body{
  background-color: #435541;
 }
 .header-1{
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 700;
 }

 .header-2{
  font-size: 9px;
 } 

 .header-2 .header-2-bold{
 font-size: 14px;
    }

 .wrapper-1 .img{
 max-width: 100%;
 }
}

Comment: Пришлите html код тоже

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x5jdo2hz/

Comment: Я хочу сделать сайт адаптированным под мобильные устройства. И там есть картинка. Я хочу её уменьшать, чтобы она была полностью показана на устройстве

Comment: Посмотрите https://jsfiddle.net/Benedetta/x5jdo2hz/3/
Задаете ширину для img 100%. Определяете размеры родительского блока. В примере я сделала 80% и поставила по центру. Вы так имеете ввиду?

Comment: Ну уже что-то похоже к истине. Сейчас протестирую

Comment: Картинку очень сильно ужало.

Comment: Как Вы хотите, чтобы она ужималась? Сейчас она до 80% от ширины экрана. Если начиная с определенной ширины экрана и меньше Вы хотите, чтобы картинка была вообще на всю ширину, то пропишите еще один медиа запрос. Уже для другой ширины. И там родительскому блоку задайте не 80%, а 100%.